# What is the default query limit on The Graph?

Tags: off-chain, the-graph

Say I have a GraphQL query like this, which I execute against a subgraph powered by [The Graph](https://thegraph.com/):

```
{
  foo {
    id
    bar
  }
}
```

What is the default number of instances of `foo` that a subgraph returns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default query limit is not mentioned in The Graph's docs. I found out the answer empirically, while debugging a bug reported by one of our [Sablier](https://sablier.finance) users.

The limit is **100 records**. So the query you shared above is equivalent to:

```
{
  foo(first: 100) {
    id
    bar
  }
}
```

The Graph supports bumping that limit to 1,000:

```
{
  foo(first: 1000) {
    id
    bar
  }
}
```

Comment: The 1k limit can be circumvented by paginating with aliases, eg. `{
  foo0(first: 1000) {
    id
    bar
  }

  foo1(first: 1000, skip: 1000) {
    id
    bar
  }
}`